# Not reading all the rows of the coulmn

Tags: java, selenium

**Scenario:**

I Fetch the NO from another Screen and then compare that NO with the NO in the table and if the NO is there then i need to click on the Radio button but the Problem over here is it is not reading all the rows which has the NO ... it reads only the first row value and fails on going to the next Step.

There is something that iam missing and not able to get what is missing in order to Read all the rows with the  NO..

Below is the Code and the Screen shot

```
List<WebElement> no = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-imoNumber')]/span"));  -= This will read the IMO NO that appears each row
int imonosize = imono.size();
VesselPositionsUtil.FetchIMOnumber(driver); = This will fetch the NO from another Screen ...
for(int i =0;i<imonosize;i++) = Then i Enter the Loop
    {
    String imonos = imono.get(i).getText(); = I Fetch the text
    System.out.println("Get the text:"+ imonos); = **In this case it fetches the first IMONo and is not reading the nextrow. This is the issue ...**
                
       if(imonos.contains(VesselPositionsUtil.FetchIMOnumber(driver))) = **Then I compare and see if the IMONO that i fetch from the other Screen is the same that appears in the Table.If yes then it will go inside the Loop.**
           {
            List<WebElement> radiobuttonoptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//table[contains(@class,'mat-table cdk-table')])[2]//following::mat-radio-button[contains(@id,'mat-radio')]"));
```

Screen Shot where I read the table which has the IMONO

**HTML: Reading the IMONO from the table**

```
<td _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted"><!----><span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">9752034</span><!----></td>
```

**2nd row which has IMONO:**

```
<td _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted"><!----><span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">00121</span><!----></td>
```

**HTML:**

```
<td _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-

cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted"><!---->

<span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">00121</span>

<!----></td>
```

**Entire HTML:**
 BOW GEMINIYELLOW9752034TBD2021-10-10

```
<tr _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="row" mat-row="" class="mat-row cdk-row ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-radio mat-column-radio ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----><mat-radio-button _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" color="primary" class="mat-radio-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" id="mat-radio-6"><label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-6-input"><span class="mat-radio-container"><span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span><span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span><input type="radio" class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-radio-6-input" tabindex="0" value="8201"><span mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span></span></span><span class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></span></label></mat-radio-button><!----><!----></span><!----><span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted"></span><!----></td><td _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vesselName mat-column-vesselName ng-star-inserted"><!----><span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">VESEL011</span><!----></td><td _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vettingStatus mat-column-vettingStatus ng-star-inserted"><!----><span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">GREEN</span><!----></td><td _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-imoNumber mat-column-imoNumber ng-star-inserted"><!----><span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">00121</span><!----></td><td _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-vouageId mat-column-vouageId ng-star-inserted"><!----><span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">TBD</span><!----></td><td _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" role="gridcell" mat-cell="" class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-lastValidityDate mat-column-lastValidityDate ng-star-inserted"><!----><span _ngcontent-jmc-c110="" class="ng-star-inserted">2035-09-25</span><!----></td><!----></tr>:
```

Added Entire Table HTML:

Vessel Name  Status  IMO Number  Voyage Id  Last Validity Date  BOW GEMINIYELLOW9752034TBD2021-10-10 VESEL011GREEN00121TBD2035-09-25

Comment: Need to see entire html of the table which has imono.

Comment: @cruisepandey - had added but is not showing

Comment: I think you have pasted only 2 td, I am asking entire table HTML

Comment: @cruisepandey - have added can you pls check now and let me know

Comment: I tried to replicate the same HTML in my local, couldn't do so, cause you are still missing to share the entire table HTML, by entire I meant with column headers as well

Comment: @cruisepandey - have added the entire table html including the header

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237196/discussion-between-jay-m-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: @cruisepandey - can add more information as well if it is required

Comment: Can someone else give inputs on this pls

Comment: check out the below code, I was on a vacation from last Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `HTML` shared by `OP` you can use `/th[contains(text(),'IMO Number')]/ancestor::thead/following-sibling::tbody/descendant::td[contains(@class,'imoNumber')]/span` xpath which is based on `IMONumber` header and would target all the `numbers` which are inside of that.

**Code :**

```
List<WebElement> imonoList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th[contains(text(),'IMO Number')]/ancestor::thead/following-sibling::tbody/descendant::td[contains(@class,'imoNumber')]/span"));  // This will read the IMO NO that appears each row
int imonosize = imonoList.size();
String previousScreenNumber = VesselPositionsUtil.FetchIMOnumber(driver); // This will fetch the NO from another Screen

for(WebElement element : imonoList) {
    String number = element.getText();
    System.out.println(number);
    if (number.contains(previousScreenNumber)) {
        System.out.println("Matched, this means we will now target the associated radio button.");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        element.findElement(By.xpath(".//../preceding-sibling::td")).click(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: will check and revert tommrow thank you so much will update tommrow - @cruisepandey